# Кто и как зарабатывает на наших вопросах и ответах?

Tags: обсуждение

- Есть площадки сети SO.

  - На них можно найти кучу полезного и не очень (пример: учебные задания).
- По сути ценностью является письменные творения.

  - Они размещаются на страничниках (сайтах) под определённым условиями использования (лицензиями).

Вопрос: знаете ли вы примеры заработка на основе размещённых здесь сообщений (за исключением самых очевидных повторялок-переводчиков)?

Comment: Прямой или косвенный заработок?

Comment: Любое использование кода из ответа в коммерческом продукте может считаться примером заработка

Comment: Имеется ввиду кроме самой компании Stack Exchange?